# Validation on timepicker according to date selection

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which i am showing Date Picker and Time Picker with validation.I validated the Time Picker as i compare current time to selected time and set message "Select Correct time",it's working correctly when select current date but when i select another date it also show "Select Correct Time".I want to make it in this way that when i select another date i should permit me to select any time .I know i have to set it according to date selection but i don't know how to set this.?

```
    Calender c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hourofday = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minuteofday = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    totalCurrenttime = hourofday + minuteofday;



private void showDateDailog() {

    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDate;


                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartDate)).setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                        .append(month + 1).append("/").append(year))
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

private void showTimeDailog() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;
            int selectedTime = hour + minute;

                if (validTime(totalCurrenttime, selectedTime)) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartTime)).setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.txt_select_correct_time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartTime)).setText(R.string.txt_Start_Time);
                }                   
        }
    }, hour, minute, timeview);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}


public boolean validTime(long current, long selected) {

    boolean isValid = false;
    if (selected > current) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @pleft that the problem with the your validation is due to your comparison not taking the **Date** into account. Writing software involving **Time** is a notoriously difficult thing, so make use of libraries to simplify the process.  If you use java classes, you can get the result you're looking for in a simpler way.

From the code, it appears that you're looking to get the user to select both a date and time which is after *now*.  The `Calendar` class can help.

```
// initializing the date to the current time
private Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

// creating a date formatter to output the dateTime in the desired format
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

private void showDateDialog() {
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, dateSetListener,c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

// pulling out the listener for clarity
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {
        date = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDate);
        String dateString = sdf.format(date.getTime());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartDate)).setText(dateString);
    }
};

private void showTimeDialog() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, timeSetListener, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), timeView);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

// pulling out the listener for clarity
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener =new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        // creating a clone of the existing date
        Calendar newCal = Calendar.class.cast(date.clone());
        // setting the hour & minute of the new calendar
        newCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
        newCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

        if (validTime(Calendar.getInstance(), newCal)) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartTime)).setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.txt_select_correct_time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartTime)).setText(R.string.txt_Start_Time);
        }
    }
};

public boolean validTime(Calendar current, Calendar selected) {
    return 0 < selected.compareTo(current);
}
```

The main takeaway from this is to make use of the power that `java.util.Calendar` class gives you.  I'd strongly suggest to take a look at the [Calendar doco](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) and [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).  Also, remember that formatting your own dates/time is something to avoid if at all possible. If you're sticking with plain java libraries, the `SimpleDateFormat` is your friend. [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/java-simpledateformat-example/).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your `validTime` method you have to pass also the date which is set by the DatePicker control and compare it with `now`. If it is a future date then return true without proceeding to compare the time.

e.g.

```
public boolean validTime(long current, long selected, long dateSet) {

    if (dateSet > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        boolean isValid = false;
        if (selected > current) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

And in your `onTimeSet` method:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

    hour = selectedHour;
    minute = selectedMinute;
    int selectedTime = hour + minute;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day);

    if (validTime(totalCurrenttime, selectedTime, cal.getTimeInMillis())) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartTime)).setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.txt_select_correct_time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTORStartTime)).setText(R.string.txt_Start_Time);
    }
}
```